# Update of Help Center > Asking

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've just found that [the proposal for Accounting SE was deleted](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82671/accounting) when I tried to answer another question on another SE site.

Please update your [Help Center > Asking](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that says

> Accounting: Accounting is a separate discipline, and there is no
>   StackExchange site dedicated to that matter yet. But a proposal for an
>   Accounting.SE site is **currently trying to get off the ground, you
>   could help**. (Emphasis mine)

Answer (score 3):

I've fixed it. I removed the sentence and link. Thanks!

> Accounting: Accounting is a separate discipline, and there is no StackExchange site dedicated to that matter yet.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck to your site.